# javafx 3d engine, resource comsumptive and error causing

Tags: java, loops, javafx

recently i've been using javafx and i've encountered a problem. In my code, i have a arraylist that checks for the nearby blocks to the player, if you can make that more resource light i would really appriciate it. After nearby blocks are added or removed from the arraylist i have some extra code to check if the user is touching one of the faces of the cube to prevent the player walking through.'Nearby' is streamed to testtouch1 method. 'tc' arraylist is then stream for each, tc is the gravity arraylist its not nessicarry to add for this error but ill add it anyway.

in testtouch1 method it checks each cube in 'near' if its touching if it is add it, again it would ill appricate it if i could get some redirection to make this more resource light, after it streams to testtouch method where it checks if the player is on top of a block and executes if it is

My code is a bit hard to read so i tried to explain it the very best and i cant share my files of my project because it has a few java libarys like javafx

the error:

```
at javafx.graphics@21/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.pickNode(Scene.java:4127)
    at javafx.graphics@21/javafx.scene.Scene.pick(Scene.java:2070)
    at javafx.graphics@21/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3937)
    at javafx.graphics@21/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler$1.run(Scene.java:3741)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

the first loop for getting 'nearby' and leading onto the rest:

```
   ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    Runnable toRun = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
           
             cc.getChildren().stream().forEach(node ->{
     if(node.getBoundsInLocal() != null){
         try {
             
          final Point3D boxPosition = node.localToScene(Point3D.ZERO);
           final Point3D cameraPosition = new Point3D(0,0,0);
               double distance = boxPosition.distance(cameraPosition);
                     System.out.println("ee");
            if(distance<100){
          
                   if( !nearby.contains(node)){
                nearby.add((Group) node);
}
            }else{
                   if(nearby.contains(node)){
                    nearby.remove((Group) node);
                   }
            }
         
            }   catch (Throwable e2){ 
      System.out.println("\n\n\n4\n\n\n");
  }
     }
        
});
            List<Rectangle> rectanglesToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
      
         for (Rectangle rect : easttouching){
        Group cube = (Group) rect.getParent();
        String id = cube.getId();
        if(!boxpos.contains(id)){
           rectanglesToRemove.add(rect);
        }
    }
         easttouching.removeAll(rectanglesToRemove);
          rectanglesToRemove.clear();
         for (Rectangle rect : northtouching){
        Group cube = (Group) rect.getParent();
        String id = cube.getId();
        if(!boxpos.contains(id)){
           rectanglesToRemove.add(rect);
        }
    } 
       northtouching.removeAll(rectanglesToRemove);
       rectanglesToRemove.clear();
        
            for (Rectangle rect : southtouching){
        Group cube = (Group) rect.getParent();
        String id = cube.getId();
        if(!boxpos.contains(id)){
           rectanglesToRemove.add(rect);
        }
    }
            southtouching.removeAll(rectanglesToRemove);
       rectanglesToRemove.clear();
                 for (Rectangle rect : westtouching){
        Group cube = (Group) rect.getParent();
        String id = cube.getId();
        if(!boxpos.contains(id)){
           rectanglesToRemove.add(rect);
        }
    }
                 southtouching.removeAll(rectanglesToRemove);
       rectanglesToRemove.clear();
              nearby.stream()
                   .forEach(node -> testtouch1((Group)node));
      List<Node> nodesToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
try{
tc.stream().forEach(node -> {
      if(node.getBoundsInLocal() != null){
                System.out.println("ee1");
    Bounds localBounds = node.getBoundsInLocal();
    Bounds sceneBounds = node.localToScene(localBounds);

    if (!hitbox.getBoundsInParent().intersects(sceneBounds)) {
        nodesToRemove.add(node);
    }
      }
});


tc.removeAll(nodesToRemove);
}catch(Throwable e){
    
        }}
    };

 
ScheduledFuture<?> handle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(toRun, 2000, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

and the test touches:

```
    void testtouch1(Group cubes) {
       if(cubes!=null&&cubes.getBoundsInLocal() != null){
              Platform.runLater(() -> {
        Bounds sceneBounds = null;
        
                 try {
    Bounds localBounds = cubes.getBoundsInLocal();
     sceneBounds = cubes.localToScene(localBounds);
       }   catch (Throwable e){ 
      System.out.println("\n\n\n3\n\n\n");
  }
        try{
             
    if (westhit.getBoundsInParent().intersects(sceneBounds)) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
           cubes.getChildren().stream()
            .filter(node -> node instanceof Rectangle)
                  .filter(node -> node.getRotationAxis() == Rotate.X_AXIS)   
                   .filter(node -> node.getRotate() == 90)   
                    .filter(node -> node.getTranslateY() == -20)   
                    .filter(node -> node.getTranslateZ() == -20)   
                   .filter(node -> node.getTranslateX() == 0) 
                   
            .forEach(node -> {

             if (!westtouching.contains((Rectangle)node)) {
                westtouching.add((Rectangle)node);
            }
            
            });
           
        
        });
    } else {
         Platform.runLater(() -> {
           cubes.getChildren().stream()
            .filter(node -> node instanceof Rectangle)
                       .filter(node -> node.getRotationAxis() == Rotate.X_AXIS)   
                   .filter(node -> node.getRotate() == 90)   
                    .filter(node -> node.getTranslateY() == -20)   
                    .filter(node -> node.getTranslateZ() == -20)   
                   .filter(node -> node.getTranslateX() == 0)   
                 
            .forEach(node -> {
            
             if (westtouching.contains((Rectangle)node) && !westtouching.isEmpty()) {
               
                westtouching.remove((Rectangle)node);
            }
            
            });
           
        
        });
    }
if (southhit.getBoundsInParent().intersects(sceneBounds)) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
           cubes.getChildren().stream()
            .filter(node -> node instanceof Rectangle)
                  .filter(node -> node.getRotationAxis() == Rotate.X_AXIS)   
                   .filter(node -> node.getRotate() == 90)   
                    .filter(node -> node.getTranslateY() == -20)   
                    .filter(node -> node.getTranslateZ() == -20)   
                   .filter(node -> node.getTranslateX() == 0)  
                    
            .forEach(node -> {
  
             if (!southtouching.contains((Rectangle)node)) {
                southtouching.add((Rectangle)node);
            }
            
            });
           
        
        });
    } else {
         Platform.runLater(() -> {
           cubes.getChildren().stream()
            .filter(node -> node instanceof Rectangle)
                       .filter(node -> node.getRotationAxis() == Rotate.X_AXIS)   
                   .filter(node -> node.getRotate() == 90)   
                    .filter(node -> node.getTranslateY() == -20)   
                    .filter(node -> node.getTranslateZ() == -20)   
                   .filter(node -> node.getTranslateX() == 0) 
                  
            .forEach(node -> {
            
             if (southtouching.contains((Rectangle)node) && !southtouching.isEmpty()) {
               
                southtouching.remove((Rectangle)node);
            }
            
            });
           
        
        });
    }
    if (northhit.getBoundsInParent().intersects(sceneBounds)) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
           cubes.getChildren().stream()
            .filter(node -> node instanceof Rectangle)
                  .filter(node -> node.getRotationAxis() == Rotate.X_AXIS)   
                   .filter(node -> node.getRotate() == 90)   
                    .filter(node -> node.getTranslateY() == -20)   
                    .filter(node -> node.getTranslateZ() == -20)   
                   .filter(node -> node.getTranslateX() == 0)  
                     
            .forEach(node -> {
  
             if (!northtouching.contains((Rectangle)node)) {
                northtouching.add((Rectangle)node);
            }
            
            });
           
        
        });
    } else {
         Platform.runLater(() -> {
           cubes.getChildren().stream()
            .filter(node -> node instanceof Rectangle)
                       .filter(node -> node.getRotationAxis() == Rotate.X_AXIS)   
                   .filter(node -> node.getRotate() == 90)   
                    .filter(node -> node.getTranslateY() == -20)   
                    .filter(node -> node.getTranslateZ() == -20)   
                   .filter(node -> node.getTranslateX() == 0)  
                   
            .forEach(node -> {
            
             if (northtouching.contains((Rectangle)node) && !northtouching.isEmpty()) {
               
                northtouching.remove((Rectangle)node);
            }
            
            });
           
        
        });
    }
  if (easthit.getBoundsInParent().intersects(sceneBounds)) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
           cubes.getChildren().stream()
            .filter(node -> node instanceof Rectangle)
                  .filter(node -> node.getRotationAxis() == Rotate.X_AXIS)   
                   .filter(node -> node.getRotate() == 90)   
                    .filter(node -> node.getTranslateY() == -20)   
                    .filter(node -> node.getTranslateZ() == -20)   
                   .filter(node -> node.getTranslateX() == 0)  
                   
            .forEach(node -> {
  
             if (!easttouching.contains((Rectangle)node)) {
                easttouching.add((Rectangle)node);
            }
            
            });
           
        
        });
    } else {
         Platform.runLater(() -> {
           cubes.getChildren().stream()
            .filter(node -> node instanceof Rectangle)
                       .filter(node -> node.getRotationAxis() == Rotate.X_AXIS)   
                   .filter(node -> node.getRotate() == 90)   
                    .filter(node -> node.getTranslateY() == -20)   
                    .filter(node -> node.getTranslateZ() == -20)   
                   .filter(node -> node.getTranslateX() == 0) 
                    
            .forEach(node -> {
            
             if (easttouching.contains((Rectangle)node) && !easttouching.isEmpty()) {
               
                easttouching.remove((Rectangle)node);
            }
            
            });
           
        
        });
    }
    cubes.getChildren().stream()
            .filter(node -> node instanceof Rectangle)
            .forEach(node -> testtouch((Rectangle) node));
        }   catch (Throwable e){ 
      System.out.println("\n\n\n2\n\n\n");
  }});
}}


 void testtouch(Rectangle cubes) {
  try {
     if(cubes.getRotationAxis() == Rotate.X_AXIS && cubes.getRotate() == 90 && cubes.getTranslateY() == -20 && cubes.getTranslateZ() == -20&& cubes.getBoundsInLocal() != null){
          Platform.runLater(()->{
   
   
     Bounds localBounds = cubes.getBoundsInLocal();
Bounds sceneBounds = cubes.localToScene(localBounds);

if (hitbox.getBoundsInParent().intersects(sceneBounds) && cubes.getOpacity()>0.5f) {
 
if(!tc.contains(cubes)){
  tc.add(cubes);
}


}else{
    if(tc.contains(cubes)){
  tc.remove(cubes);
    }


   

}});}
  } catch (Throwable e){ 
      System.out.println("\n\n\n1\n\n\n");
  }
}
```

The error appears after this code is ran for a while and i sometimes get errors from this code in other times like this error

```
at javafx.graphics@21/javafx.scene.Parent.updateBounds(Parent.java:1834)
    at javafx.graphics@21/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2615)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:401)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:430)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:592)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:572)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:565)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:352)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
```

and sometimes a index out of bounds error, i know these errors come from here because i used various try and catches but they dont always stop it sometimes, ive fixed most of the index out of bounds error but it seems to be persistant

it would really help if you could fix it and if you can optimise or give a way to make it less resource comsumptive

Comment: Problems that happen _sometimes_ make me think of synchronization errors; in particular, your fragment appears to be updating the scene graph from a background thread; see [*Creating Transitions and Timeline Animations*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/animations.htm#JFXTE149) or [*Concurrency in JavaFX*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm).

Comment: You *must not* access a live scene graph from a background thread, which you appear to be doing in you `scheduler`